# List is showing null when should show the data from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, full-text-search, flutter-test

I  want to search in firestore data but the list is not showing me data from firestore. I want to return my list with firestore data but it is not showing me and i want to search in list data according to my choice.

Please tell me where I am wrong?

```dart
class serachDeligat extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  String ref = 'items';

  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getSearch() async =>
      await _firestore.collection(ref).getDocuments().then((snaps) {
        return snaps.documents;
      });
  List<Map> search = <Map>[];
  Future getDocs() async {
    search = await (await getSearch()).map((item) => item.data).toList();
    return search;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getDocs();
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildActions
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          print('$search');
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildLeading
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will share what I did in one of my projects which had the same problem.I tried many ways but all of them end up with a null.Then I change my function with the help of StreamSubscription.This will change the data even after retrieving from firestore since it maintains a connection with firestore.I loaded data inside the initstate.

```
  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> dailyTaskSubscription;
  ProgressDialog progressDialog;
  List<ScheduleTask> mondayTaskList = List();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      mondayTaskList = List();
      dailyTaskSubscription?.cancel();
      dailyTaskSubscription = scheduleService
          .getDailyTaskList(studentId, 'monday')
          .listen((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
        final List<ScheduleTask> tasks = snapshot.documents
            .map((documentSnapshot) =>
                ScheduleTask.fromMap(documentSnapshot.data))
            .toList();
    });
  }
```

Comment: super.initState(); is not working in SearchDelegate class

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer to my question
I should use the await in my onPressed

```
class serachDeligat extends SearchDelegate<String>{
  Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  String ref = 'items';
  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getSearch() async =>
      await _firestore.collection(ref).getDocuments().then((snaps) {
        return snaps.documents;
      });
  List<Map> search = <Map>[];
  Future getDocs() async {
    search=await
        (await getSearch()).map((item) => item.data).toList();
    return search;}
  @override
  void initState() {
    getDocs();
    super.query;
  }
  List<Map> searchAi = <Map>[];
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildActions
    return[IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
      onPressed: ()async {
        searchAi=await getDocs();

        print(searchAi);

      },),];}

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildLeading
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: (){
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      child: Center(),);}

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();}}
```